# Control flow syntax in c++

Tags: c++, syntax, control-flow

With the following c++ example(indention was left out in purpose).

```
if(condA)          // if #1
if(condB)          // if #2
if(condC)          // if #3
if(condD)          // if #4
funcA();
else if(condD)     // else #1 if #5
funcB();
else if(condE)     // else #2 if #6
funcC();
else               // else #3
funcD();
else if(condF)     // else #4 if #7
funcE();
else               // else #5
funcF();
```

What `else` refers to what `if` and what is the rule about this? (yes I know using `{ }` will solve this).

Comment: You've stumbled on a problem known as the dangling else problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else

Comment: damn too many right answers and only one that can be accepted

Comment: Find out who the original author is and brace and indent him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeadMG is right. Just in case you are interested, the rule is

> `else` is attached to the last free
>   (that is, unprotected by braces and
>   without corresponding else) `if`.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(condA)          // if #1
    if(condB)          // if #2
        if(condC)          // if #3
            if(condD)          // if #4
                funcA();
            else if(condD)     // else #1 if #5
                funcB();
            else if(condE)     // else #2 if #6
                funcC();
            else               // else #3
                funcD();
        else if(condF)     // else #4 if #7
            funcE();
        else               // else #5
            funcF();
```

Answer (score 3):

Each `else` always refers to the inner-most `if` possible.

So

```
if (a)
if (b) B;
else C;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (a) {
  if (b) B;
  else C;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever write code like this in a production environment. It will bite you.

Comment: It seems like more of a theoretical problem, and a very practical one when analyzing languages.

Comment: It did bit me, but I didn't write the code, and I needed to know wtf does it do.

Comment: @Stargazer: Yes you are right, but only for those who write programming languages. Which is very few of us. 
@Dani: Ouch, I'm sorry you had to maintain that code. My condolences. :)

Comment: @ C Johnson: I had never seen code like that written outside of a theoretical environment, so I assumed it must be a theoretical question :). My condolences as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "Dangling else" problem. The convention to solve this is to attach the 'else' to the nearest 'if' statement.

[Dangling else wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else)

Comment: Edited so it doesn't imply the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

C++ knows which else matches which if, and C++ compilers have just-fine parsers that sort this out in flash.  The problem is the *you* aren't good at this.

Run this through a [C++ prettyprinter](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/CppFormatter.html) and the result formatted text will make it very clear.